# How to load WordPress comments in real-time as they come in? (Ajax)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

We are trying to find a way to load WordPress comments in real time so that if a new comment comes in to any of our posts, it should show up in real time without the need to refresh the page.

How can we get AJAX to constantly check for new comments? A short delay is fine, so something like every 10 seconds would be fine.

Comment: I would recommend using websockets if you're constantly requesting since it can put a strain on your server

Comment: @KRUKUSA WebSockets may sound like a good idea but it probably isn't. Periodically sending discreet HTTP requests is a lot easier to implement, and they do not require a continuous full-duplex connection, for the life of the page, to work. As long as the requests do not overlap, and you do not flood the server, then HTTP requests are not that expensive.

Comment: @Sverri M. Olsen Sending discreet http requests is surely easier to implement, but websockets aren't an replacement for http. Any who for real-time data I strongly believe websockets for Javascript applicaitons/games are the way to go. With HTTP requests the server can't data unless the client has explicitly requested it but websockets allow the server to send data whenever it wants, allowing lower latency. Basically websockets were are basically http requests.

Comment: @KRUKUSA Yeah, but this is not an app or game. Receiving new comments "every 10 seconds" does not really warrant using WebSockets. It can be done, but it is harder to implement and the benefits, if any, are not apparent at all.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I'm sure he meant up to "every 10 seconds", meaning if you could do better than 10 seconds, he would prefer that way. I still know that there are more advantages of Websockets compared to http request. Http handshakes are not realistic

Comment: Wordpress and Websockets in same sentence sounds very much like manure and diamonds on the same person.. Technically, using a websocket to notify JS app to do AJAX request for comments might be extremely well. But issuing a request for new comments every 10 seconds is 1) **way, way faster to develop** 2) doesn't require learning about WS and the painful process of finding and setting up WS server and 3) it's not really *that* strainful for the server.

Comment: With [Heartbeat](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/heartbeat-api-using-heartbeat-in-a-plugin--wp-32496)

Comment: Does anyone have some sample code?